# Deserialize Jackson 2.3 returns null objects

Tags: android, jackson

I'm using Jackson 2.3 and I'm having some problems deserializing.

I have these class and interface:

FollowValue:

```
public class FollowValue implements Value{

@JsonProperty("id");
public long id;

@JsonProperty("time_creation")
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
public Date timeCreation;

@JsonProperty("follower")
private User follower;

@JsonProperty("user")
private User user;

@Override
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public Date getTimeCreation() {
return timeCreation;
}
}
```

Value:

```
public interface Value {

public long getId();
public Date getTimeCreation();

}
```

When I read the FollowValue like this:

```
FollowValue value = mapper.readValue(valueNode.traverse(), FollowValue.class);
```

No exception is showed and follower and user are null. I've searched for a solution but I only find documentation for previous versions of Jackson. How can I deserialize this?

Thanks!

This is the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
"type": "Follow",
"value": {
        "id": 205,
        "time_creation": "2014-03-04T14:54:53+0100",
        "follower": {
            "id": 62,
            "username": "email@email.com",
            "fullname": "Meri Riera",

        },
        "user": {
            "id": 24,
            "username": "email@email.com",
            "fullname": "Héctor",

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do the **valueNode** structure looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
mapper.readValue(valueNode.traverse(objectCodec), FollowValue.class);
```

I don't know if it's the best approach, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your jsonc data does not fit in a format of `FollowValue` format I think it won't be parsed.

Try to annotate your main entity with `@JsonRootName(value = "value")`

Then after instantiating your `ObjectMapper` object, configure it with:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Still have a null reference?